# MongoDB Aggregation, how do I get the sum of a field?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB's aggregation seems rather complex, I'd appreciate it if someone could give me a good, simple example for me to firmly grasp the basics.

Think of a collection containing documents that contain file names and file sizes.

How can I get the sum of all the files' sizes?

Additionally, how do I get the sum of only files that start with the letter 'a'?

Comment: Have you seen this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example program for both queries using the [Asynchronous Java Driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/):

```java
package example;

import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationGroupField.set;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationGroupId.constantId;
import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.QueryBuilder.where;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoCollection;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.Document;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.BuilderFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.DocumentBuilder;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.element.ArrayElement;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.Aggregate;

public class FileSizeAggregation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient client = MongoFactory
                .createClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        MongoCollection collection = client.getDatabase("test").getCollection(
                "test");
        collection.delete(BuilderFactory.start()); // Clear the collection.

        // Create some documents.
        DocumentBuilder doc = BuilderFactory.start();
        for (char first = 'a'; first <= 'z'; ++first) {
            for (char second = 'a'; second <= 'z'; ++second) {
                doc.reset();

                doc.add("name", new String(new char[] { first, second }));
                doc.add("size", 10);

                collection.insert(doc);
            }
        }

        // Count all file "sizes".
        Aggregate.Builder builder = new Aggregate.Builder();
        builder.group(constantId("sum"), 
                      set("total").sum("size"), 
                      set("count").count());

        System.out.println(new ArrayElement("pipeline", builder.build()
                .getPipeline()));

        Iterable<Document> docs = collection.aggregate(builder.build());
        for (Document d : docs) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }

        // Count all file sizes that start with "a"
        builder.reset();
        builder.match(where("name").matches(Pattern.compile("^a")));
        builder.group(constantId("sum"), 
                      set("total").sum("size"), 
                      set("count").count());

        System.out.println(new ArrayElement("pipeline", builder.build()
                .getPipeline()));

        docs = collection.aggregate(builder.build());
        for (Document d : docs) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

}
```

I have the program dumping out the aggregation pipeline so you can see what it looks like in the shell.  Lets look at the output.

```js
pipeline : [
  {
    '$group' : {
      '_id' : 'sum',
      total : { '$sum' : '$size' },
      count : { '$sum' : 1 }
    }
  }
]
```

This is the pipeline for the first query, sum the size of the files. We use the "$group" operator as the only stage in the pipeline. We assign a constant id ('_id' : 'sum') to group all documents into a single result document. The total and count lines then sum the size field in each document and return a document count.  The result of this aggregation looks like:

```js
{
  '_id' : 'sum',
  total : 6760,
  count : 676
}
```

676 documents (26 * 26) and since each file is "10" the total is 6760.  Looks good.  Next aggregation!

This time we want to only sum up the documents where the file name starts with the letter 'a'.

```js
pipeline : [
  {
    '$match' : {
      name : { '$regex' : { $regex : '^a' } }
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$group' : {
      '_id' : 'sum',
      total : { '$sum' : '$size' },
      count : { '$sum' : 1 }
    }
  }
]
```

The only real change is that we add a step in the pipeline before the $group to filter or $match the subset of document.  In this case the regular expression '^a' fits the bill. (The double $regex document is a side effect of the way the driver encodes the JSON.  The first $regex is the "match" operator and the second represents a MongoDB extension to represent a Regular Expression.)

```js
{
  '_id' : 'sum',
  total : 260,
  count : 26
}
```

And the result look right.  26 documents and 260 for the total.

HTH,
Rob.